# Form data is not uploaded and alert not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and followed a tutorial to make a pop form. The data filled by the user was supposed to appear in the console and that doesn't happen. I would also like to create an alert for when people click on the submit button so I added the last few lines that you'll see in the JavaScipt code, but it's not working as well. Hope that this is detailed enough and that someone can help me.

Here is the HTML

```
<h1>
                I'd love to chat with you about your upcoming project.
              </h1>
              <div class="intro-text">
                Fill out the form bellow to get in touch. Either for a budget information or to book a meeting to discuss
                any ideas that you might have, you can contact me for any
                clarification you need. I'll get back to you in 2-3 days.
              </div>
              <div class="row open-form">
                <div class="open-btn">
                  <button id="show-modal"><strong>Open Form</strong></button>
                </div>
              </div>
<script src="./JavaScript/action_page.js"></script>
    <div class="modal modal--hidden">
      <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="close">
          <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="closeMe()"></i>
        </div>
        <h1>Ask away</h1>
        <form id="submit">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
          <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" />
          <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
          <button class="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>
```

And JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("show-modal").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "flex";
});

function closeMe() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "none";
}

document.querySelector("#show-modal").addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleModal();
  let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#show-modal"));
  console.log(
    "Name:" + formData.get("name"),
    "Email:" + formData.get("email"),
    "Subject:" + formData.get("subject"),
    "Message:" + formData.get("message")
  );
});

document.getElementById("#show-modal").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  alert("Thank you for your message!");
});
```

Here is the page if you want to have a look: https://giacomosorbi.github.io/joanaoli09-module-i/contact.html

Comment: which html element has this id -> `show-modal`. I dont see it anywhere in your snipept

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Of course it will show it on frontend/user-side. But as you stated, additional checking should be done on server side.

Comment: It was before the code that I showed, forgot to add it my bad. It's correct now.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Stop spreading misinformation and check your references. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping https://jsfiddle.net/esdL0whf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to:

(Removed toggleModal() as there is no defination for it)

```js
document.getElementById("show-modal").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "flex";
});

function closeMe() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "none";
}

document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#submit"));
  console.log(
    "Name:" + formData.get("name"),
    "Email:" + formData.get("email"),
    "Subject:" + formData.get("subject"),
    "Message:" + formData.get("message")
  );
  alert("Thank you!!!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
                I'd love to chat with you about your upcoming project.
              </h1>
              <div class="intro-text">
                Fill out the form bellow to get in touch. Either for a budget information or to book a meeting to discuss
                any ideas that you might have, you can contact me for any
                clarification you need. I'll get back to you in 2-3 days.
              </div>
              <div class="row open-form">
                <div class="open-btn">
                  <button id="show-modal"><strong>Open Form</strong></button>
                </div>
              </div>
<script src="./JavaScript/action_page.js"></script>
    <div class="modal modal--hidden">
      <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="close">
          <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="closeMe()"></i>
        </div>
        <h1>Ask away</h1>
        <form id="submit">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
          <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" />
          <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
          <button class="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This is not just what the OP wanted. There is more needed to be done according to the question and formData issue. This answer is just showing alert.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Modified Answer.

Comment: @JoanaOliveira Accept and upvote if it helped. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, move `<script>` tag on the end of the html document, because you are trying to find elements in html that aren't rendered yet.

As so:

```
    <div class="modal modal--hidden">
      <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="close">
          <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="closeMe()"></i>
        </div>
        <h1>Ask away</h1>
        <form id="submit">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
          <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" />
          <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
          <button class="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>

<script src="./JavaScript/action_page.js"></script>
```

Second, your `addEventListener("submit",...` should be on form element, not on modal button-

Comment: I've done these changes and still nothing appears on the console and none alert when submitting :/